# How to cycle through json items if multiple values are present?

Tags: jquery, json

I want to populate a select box with the data comming from a json feed. My function does read the json, and cycles through its values.

The result I am getting is not what I expeced, something is wrong within the loop.

My json:

```
   "case": {
      "1": {
        "id": "47",
        "name": "Stahl",
        "n": 239
      },
      "2": {
        "id": "111",
        "name": "Titan",
        "n": 16
      }
    },
```

My function:

```
  if (obj.facetes.case  ){
    $('#case_m').selectmenu( "enable" );
    $.each(obj.facetes.case, function(key,valueObj){
          Object.keys(valueObj || {}).forEach(function(k) {
          $('#case_m').append(
            $('<option></option>').val(valueObj['id']).html(valueObj['name'] + ' ('+valueObj['n']+')')
          );
       })
     })
  }
  else{
    $('#case_m').selectmenu( "disable" );
  }
```

The result:

```
<select name="case_m" id="case_m" data-mini="true" class="filter_watch">
    <option>Material Gehäuse auswählen</option>
    <option value="47">Stahl (239)</option>
    <option value="47">Stahl (239)</option>
    <option value="47">Stahl (239)</option>
    <option value="111">Titan (16)</option>
    <option value="111">Titan (16)</option>
    <option value="111">Titan (16)</option>
</select>
```

The values are three times there, same as the amount of elements per item. How can I change the function in order to get unique results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rory mentioned, The issue is due to the inner loop through Object.keys, which you don't actually need. I've written a slightly different logic.

```js
var obj = {};
obj.facetes = {};
obj.facetes = {"case": {
      "1": {
        "id": "47",
        "name": "Stahl",
        "n": 239
      },
      "2": {
        "id": "111",
        "name": "Titan",
        "n": 16
      }
    }
}

if (obj.facetes.case  ){

    $.each(obj.facetes.case, function(key, value) {   
         $('#case_m')
             .append($("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value",value['id'])
                        .text(value['name']+' ('+value['n']+')')); 
    });

  }
  else{
    $('#case_m').selectmenu( "disable" );
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="case_m" id="case_m" data-mini="true" class="filter_watch">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the inner loop through `Object.keys`, which you don't actually need. You can access the properties directly from `valueObj` instead, eg `valueObj.name`.

That being said you can go further and make the code even more succinct by using `map()` to build an array of HTML strings to populate the `select` with, like this:

```js
var obj = {
  facetes: {
    "case": {
      "1": { "id": "47", "name": "Stahl", "n": 239 },
      "2": { "id": "111", "name": "Titan", "n": 16 }
    }
  }
}

if (obj.facetes.case) {
  // $('#case_m').selectmenu("enable");

  var options = Object.keys(obj.facetes.case).map(function(k) {
    var item = obj.facetes.case[k];
    return `<option value="${item.id}">${item.name} (${item.n})</option>`;
  });
  $('#case_m').append(options);
} else {
  // $('#case_m').selectmenu("disable");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="case_m" id="case_m" data-mini="true" class="filter_watch">
  <option>Material Gehäuse auswählen</option>
</select>
```

Note that I only commented the `selectmenu()` references as the snippet doesn't include that library.